# Take a screenshot of specific application

Tags: linux, screenshot, compiz

I'm running compiz under Linux.  I know compiz is able to keep all workspaces running at the same time, so if I want to take a screenshot of an application, regardless of which workspace it is on, what should I do?  (Any language.)

Answer (score 1):

`xwd -id x_window_id | xwdtopnm | pnmtopng > image.png`

Or use the -name option to xwd.